# If every subset of metric space (M,d) is compact, then is M finite?

Tags: metric-spaces

Given a metric space $(M, d)$ such that any subset E of M is compact.
is M a finite set?

I think it is false but cannot find a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is true. notice that every compact set in metric space is closed. So, every subset of $M$ is closed .So, $M$ is closed. Then every subset is open.  Consider the following $$W=\{\{x\}\colon x\in M\}$$ is an open cover for $M$. So, if every element omitted from $W$ the reminder can not cover $M.$
I hope  that helps